# c++ class members functions: how to write these functions?

Tags: c++, class, oop, object

In my Object Oriented c++ course, we have to write this class that I have put below.

```
Point
    class Point{
    public:
        Point( double x = 0, double y = 0 );
        double getX() const;
        double getY() const;
        Point & setX( double x );    //  mutator, returning reference to self
        Point & setY( double y );
        const Point & output() const;
        double distance( const Point & other ) const;
    private:
        double xPoint, yPoint;
    }; // class Point
```

my question is...I can't find any information on how the functions setX, setY, and output should work. They are the same type as the class itself and I have written what I would expect them to look like below. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong and maybe some more specifics of how these functions are working?
The setX function should change xPoint in the object, the setY should do the same for the yPoint and output should simply output them.

```
Point & Point::setX( double x )
{
xPoint = x;
}   

Point & Point::setY( double y )
{
Ypoint = y;
}

const Point & Point::output() const
{
cout << xPoint << yPoint;
}
```

Comment: Just add a return `*this` at the end of your setX and setY: you are returning a reference to your class, so that for example you can do: `p0.setX(1.23).setY(3.45)`, with of course `p0` an instance of Point. In the output function, put a separator between xPoint and yPoint, like a space. You say `They are the same type as the class itself `: don't confuse a variable type with the type returned by a function/method: those method return an instance of the class to which they belong.

Comment: You also have a small typo in `setY`: it should be `yPoint`, not `Ypoint`.  C++ is case sensitive.

Comment: Thank you so much! would you be able to elaborate on why putting this *this pointer for those functions works?

Answer (score 3):

Just add a `return *this;` at the end of your setX and setY: you are returning a reference to your object, so that for example you can do: `p0.setX(1.23).setY(3.45)`, with of course `p0` an instance of Point. In the output function, put a separator between xPoint and yPoint, like a space. You say `They are the same type as the class itself`: don't confuse a variable type with the type returned by a function/method: the method `setX`, `setY` and `output` return a reference to an instance of the class to which they belong. Note that the reference returned by output is `const`, so you can do:

```
p0.setX(1.23).setY(3.45).output();
```

But not:

```
p0.output().setX(1.23);
```

As `setX` is not a const method (it doesn't declare that it won't modify the data inside the class instance to which it belongs).

You can call instead:

```
double x = p0.output().getX();
```

because `getX` is a const method.

Note: I am not saying you should use the methods in this way, but the point is to show what potentially you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Setters are public metods thats allow you change private members of the class, they don't have return type so `setX`, `setY` should be `void` not `Point`:

```
void set(double x); // Declaration
void Point::setX( double x ) // Definition outside Point.h
{
   xPoint = x;
}
```

Same with `output` should be `void`, rest is fine you can define it whatever you wish to display it, you can change it like this:

```
void Point::output() const
{
  cout << "(" << xPoint << ", " << yPoint << ")";
}
```

Comment: I completely agree but this is what my professor wanted us to do, we had them as void and we had to change them.

Answer (score 0):

`setX()` will probably change the value of the `pointX` member, and return a reference to the object being acted on.

So an implementation might be something like

```
Point &Point::setX(double xval)
{
    if (IsValid(xval)) pointX = xval;    // ignore invalid changes
    return *this;
}
```

This can (assuming other member functions and operators are being used correctly) be used in things like this

```
#include <iostream>
 // declaration of Point here
int main()
{
     Point p;
     std::cout << p.setX(25).setY(30).getX() << '\n';
}
```

While this example isn't particularly useful (it shows what is possible) the chaining of member function calls is useful in various circumstances.  For example, this technique is actually the basis on which `iostream` insertion and extraction operators work, and allow multiple things to be inserted/extracted to/from a stream in a single statement.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of the `setX` and `setY` functions says

```
// mutator, returning reference to self
```

Your implementation does the *mutation*, but you've failed to complete the contract that this function is supposed to satisfy: it's supposed to *return a reference to itself*.

`this` is a pointer to the object you're invoking the method on, and so adding the line

```
return *this;
```

would complete the contract.

---

This is an aside, but it may help you understand why anyone would want to use such a 'strange' design.

You may be familiar with ordinary assignment being used in ways such as

```
a = b = 0;

if((result = some_function()) == 0) {
    // Do something in the `result == 0` case
} else {
    // Do something in the `result != 0` case
}
```

and other similar things. The first example sets both `a` and `b` to be `0`. The second example stores the return value of the function call into the variable `result`, and then branches based on whether that value is `0` or not.

The way this works is that `x = y` is a *binary operator* that which has the side effect of copying the value of `y` into `x`, and then returns that value (technically a reference to `x`) so that it may be used in the surrounding expression.

So when you write `a = b = 0`, this is parsed as `a = (b = 0)`, and has the effect of making `b` zero, and then evaluates to `a = 0` which is then evaluated and makes `a` zero. Similarly for the branching example.

This is something people like to do when writing code (it's a completely separate topic whether or not this is good style), so when people design new types with `operator=` methods, they design them to support this usage, by making them return a reference to the object assigned to. e.g.

```
MyClass& MyClass::operator=(arg a)
{
    // Copy the value of `a` into this object
    return *this;
}
```

The other assignment operators, like `operator+=` also work this way.

Now, when you're used to this usage, it is a small step to extend it to other functions that sort of act like assignment, like `setX` and `setY`. This has the additional convenience of making it easy to chain modifications, as in `point.setX(3).setY(7)`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I understand that '*this' is a dereferenced pointer and *this usually points to a clone of the current object but since it is returning a reference,  it returns to the current object. What would be the reason that we couldn't return this without the asterisk?